# Why did Lord Darth Vader never wear a hood?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

In late 1977 several *Star Wars* merchandise poster print advertisements produced by Joe Kubert School appeared in Marvel Comics. One of those prints entitled "Darth Vader Lives" depicted a Hooded Darth Vader.

Even though it is well known that Anakin Skywalker wore a visually effective hood, like many Jedi Masters and Sith Lords, I understood that an Armored Darth Vader would no longer have the need to wear a hood but since the arrival on the *Star Wars* arena of his grandson, Kylo Ren, I ask if there is a canon or Legends explanation about why Darth Vader never wore a hood?

[image: 1977 Joe Kubert School Star Wars Print Advertisement]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Try and pull a hood over a motorcycle helmet and I'd think this answers itself.

Comment: Not to mention that the shape of the helmet obviously has the line of a hood anyway.

Comment: @rld Have you seen the size of the hoods in _Star Wars_!? Those things can fit whole Star Destroyers in them!

Comment: Maybe he does not want to be confused with Doctor Doom

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whoever drew this print took a *lot* of artistic liberties. Observe, for example, the yellow lightsaber, that's incorrectly referred to as a "lazar sword".

Comment: The point of a hood is to hide your face. The point of Darth Vader is to *be* the face of the Empire, the highly visible enforcer. It'd be a bit of a contradiction.

Comment: @F1Krazy - American comics artists Joe Kubert and Richard Veitch were among the artists/leterrers, and let's remember that this was 1977 and probably they had scarce reference material.

Comment: Wow, that brings me back.

Comment: That's not Vader, its clearly "Lord Darth Vadar"